# Apply a function with multiple outputs to dataframe that is split by factors in the tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have a dataframe of the form:

```
y       x1      x2      x3      factor
-----------------------------------------------
numeric numeric numeric numeric factor_level_1
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
numeric numeric numeric numeric factor_level_2
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
numeric numeric numeric numeric factor_level_3
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
```

I am trying to apply the `commonalityCoefficients` function from the `yhat` package to subsets of my dataframe, split by `factor`.

From the docs,  `commonalityCoefficients` has arguments: `commonalityCoefficients(dataMatrix, dv, ivlist, imat=FALSE)` with `dataMatrix` a dataframe, and `dv` and `ivlist` strings containing column labels from the dataframe. Importantly (I think), **it returns two tables** that contain the results of the commonality analysis.

I suppose I could use a loop but I would really like to use a tidyverse method to do it. I've tried various combinations such as subsetting the dataframe with `split()` or `dplyr::group_by()`; and applying the function with `purrr::map()` and `purrr::walk()` family functions but I can't find a combination that works.

I guess the problem is that each function call returns two tables and it is not trivial to capture each of those tables? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidyverse way:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(yhat)
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(50),
                 x1 = runif(50),
                 x2 = runif(50),
                 x3 = runif(50),
                 ff1 = gl(n = 5, k = 10, length = 50, labels = LETTERS[1:5]))

ivlst <- as.list(setdiff(names(df), c("y", "ff1")))

results <-
  df %>%
  group_by(ff1) %>%
  group_map( ~ commonalityCoefficients(., dv = "y", ivlist = ivlst))
```